# In JIRA, when I moved issues from one project to another, they don't show up in Agile view, but show up in project view

Tags: jira

Recently I moved a bunch of JIRA issues from one of my projects to another.

When I created a JIRA Agile board for the new project (just based off on the new project, no special filters) I could not see any of the issues I created. Whenever I create a new issue, it also doesn't show up.

When I do a query fro the project issues, they all show up.

I checked the Board filter: `project = IT ORDER BY Rank ASC`

Seems fine...

Any ideas on troubleshooting.

Comment: Make sure you have not checked any of the Quick Filter at the top.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a very similar issue.  For me, I had a 'Work Sub-Filter' auto applied when I created the board.  Removing that fixed the problem.

You can find the setting on the general settings page of board configuration:

[image: Jira settings screen]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Scrum Board in Jira then you would be able to switch views between **Plan** and **Work**. **Plan** view will show all the Jira tickets, where as **Work** mode will show only the current sprint's tasks. Create a new sprint and assign that sprint number to Jira tickets, this will populate the **Work** view of your Agile Board.

[image]

<sub>Creative Commons image copied from https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Using+Plan+Mode</sub>

Comment: I am in Plan mode. No dice :( However when I started with JIRA this was definitely confusing (so useful to community)